# Highchart, Combined Two Chart in One with different data from Meteor Collection

Tags: highcharts, meteor

I am trying compare Donation vs Disbursement and wanted to combine two Highchart into one however they have different data resulting from different query in my Meteor Collection.

Below are my result data in a sample query instance.

```
Donation:
 Label ['May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug']
 Value [106.4, 129.2, 144.0]

Disbursement:
 Label ['Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct']
 Value [ 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
```

Here's the jfiddle link [Highchart- two charts](http://jsfiddle.net/teEQ3/8/)

I did tried the normal two data sets in Highchart but only works when the both query have the same label values and when not then it started to show erroneously.

Answer (score 1):

How about using one concatenated categories, and for each of points use proper index of that category?  Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/teEQ3/9/

```
$('#container1').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct'] // result from  query
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        id: 'someId',
        data: [ [0, 106.4], [1, 129.2], [2, 144.0]] // result from  query
    }, {
        id: 'someId2',
        data: [ [1, 148.5], [2, 216.4], [3, 194.1], [4, 95.6], [5, 54.4]] // result from  query
    }]
});
```

As you said: two charts combined in one.

Comment: So how do I combined the two results categories into one?

Comment: Just merge arrays, without duplicates. The problem will be with proper order. Can't you just assume your categories always starts with Jan and end with Dec? Then just find proper point's index.

Comment: I was thinking of making a dummy data with zero value to populate my collection so it will always have the same category =)

Comment: Instead of 0 use 'null' - it will take space on a chart, but won't display any bar/line/marker on 0-value.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to process the data after your query.

I would do this by finding the highest/lowest category, and doing a loop to fill in all values in between.
At each pass through the loop, you build one array for you categories, and two separate arrays for your data series, including both the x and y values.

How to do it specifically will depend on how you are getting your data and what environment you are working in.

Comment: can you show me base on the array data above using javascript?